# Currency sign not readable in IAPv3 return JSON

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-purchase, android-billing

I'm using Google Play Billing Library for IAPs. It works fine, except for price queries.

This is what returned JSON looks like when quering for inventory (log retrieved from logcat):

```
Got sku details: 
SkuDetails:{
"title":"Remove ads",
"price":"1,10┬áÔé¼",
"type":"inapp",
"description":"No more ads",
"price_amount_micros":890000,
"price_currency_code":"EUR",
"productId":"remove_ads"
}
```

and when I use `getPrice()` to retrieve localized price, it looks like this: `1,10┬á?`

I initialized the iap helper like this in `onCreate()`

```
iap_helper = new IabHelper(this, app_key);
iap_helper.enableDebugLogging(true);
iap_helper.startSetup(this);
```

then at `onIabSetupFinished` I call

```
iap_helper.queryInventoryAsync(this);
```

Comment: check my below answer.

Answer (score 0):

check below link, it is working for me:

> http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#QueryDetails

You haven't pass your product id while requesting for inventory. I think it will give random price if you haven't pass sku_product while requesting for inventory because of not getting particular product for response.

> List additionalSkuList = new List(); // you can take array list
>   instead not sure it is working or not.
>
> additionalSkuList.add(SKU_APPLE);
>   additionalSkuList.add(SKU_BANANA);
>
> iap_helper.queryInventoryAsync(true, additionalSkuList,
>   mQueryFinishedListener);

```
    IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory)       {

          if (result.isFailure()) {
             // handle error
             return;
           }

           String applePrice =
              inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_APPLE).getPrice();
           String bananaPrice =
              inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_BANANA).getPrice();

           // update the UI   
      }

    }
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: If you have still the problem then check this link and update your code from the marketbilling source folder. check this issue: https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=75&can=7&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Google%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary seems like same compare to your issue. Let me know my answer is helpful to you or not.

Comment: Nope, it makes no difference whether I supply AdditionalSkuList or not. It returns a correct list of IAP items on both occasion with correct detail, except for currency sign. Default price is set at 0.89€ in my developer console and 1.10€ (incl. taxes) for my country, so the numerical values seem to be correct. Only € (euro-sign) turns into a character garbage.